# Как поместить svg иконку в центр круга?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Как поместить svg иконку в центр круга?

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Вк">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}

.circle img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Вк">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
.circle{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Вк">
</div>
```